# Update a button in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I was hoping to find some help here. I'm learning Javascript while working on a project and I have a little problem with updating the status of the display of a button on my page.

So I want to have a kinda condition that will make appear a button and make it disappear if the condition isn't there!

I have two buttons that should have a certain number of clicks on each of them (let say 12 and 13), I've been able to get a condition that if button1 == 12 && button2 == 13 then change the stats of the button to block instead of hidden. But the problem once the condition has been done, if I click another time on one of the two-button, the button (the one is supposed to appear after the condition) stay on even if the condition aren't there anymore.

```js
//var clickNeeded = 12;
var clicks = 0;
var clicks1 = 0;


function countDown() {
    clicks += 1;
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = clicks;
    if (clicks == 12 && clicks1 == 13){
        document.getElementById("step1").style.display = 'block';
    }
};
function countDown1() {
    clicks1 += 1;
    document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML = clicks1;
    if (clicks == 12 && clicks1 == 13){
        document.getElementById("step1").style.display = 'block';
    }
};

if (clicks != 12 && clicks1 != 13){
    document.getElementById("step1").style.display = 'hidden';
}



function messageAfficher() {
    document.getElementById("enigme").style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
body{
    background-color: black; 
    
}

@font-face{
    font-family: 'hacked';
    src: url(font/Hacked-KerX.ttf);
    font-style: normal;
}

.header{
    text-align: center;
    margin: 50px 100px;
    font-family: hacked;
}

.header h1{
    color: purple;
    font-size: 80px;
    margin: 50px    
}

.header p{
    color: purple;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: justify;
    padding-right: 100px;
    padding-left: 100px; 
}

.enigme {
    color: aliceblue;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: hacked;
}

.step {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="fonction.js"></script> 
        <title>Escape Game</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
<!--===========================================================================================================================-->
    <body>
        
        <div class="header">
            <h1>Bienvenue dans cette aventure!</h1>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<br>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="step">
            <button id="test" onclick="countDown()">0</button>
        </div>
        <div class="step">
            <button id="test1" onclick="countDown1()">0</button>
        </div>
        <div class="step">
            <button id="step1" onclick="messageAfficher()" style="display:none">Où suis-je?</button>
        </div>
        <div class="enigme">
            <p id="enigme" style="display:none">Coordonne</p>
        </div>
        
    </body>
<!--===========================================================================================================================--> 
</html>
```

So my only idea was to add an If condition after my function, but as I see it's not working and it's kinda logic that is not. So I'm kinda lost here ^^'
Thank you in advance! :D

Comment: Your `if (clicks != 12 && clicks1 != 13)` only runs once on page load and not inside the functions after changes occur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `display` should be `none` instead of `hidden`.

`hidden` works with `visibility`.

Also, you need to put an `else` condition which will hide `step1`. currently you've written it outside and it won't run on click of the buttons.

```
function countDown() {
    clicks += 1;
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = clicks;
    if (clicks == 12 && clicks1 == 13){
        document.getElementById("step1").style.display = 'block';
    }else{
        document.getElementById("step1").style.display = 'none';
     }
};
function countDown1() {
    clicks1 += 1;
    document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML = clicks1;
    if (clicks == 12 && clicks1 == 13){
        document.getElementById("step1").style.display = 'block';
    }else{
        document.getElementById("step1").style.display = 'none';
     }
};
```

Also, since the same block of code is repeating, you might like to extract it out and put in another function to re-use it. And use `===` instead of lose comparison `==`

```
    function countDown() {
        clicks += 1;
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = clicks;
        hiddenOrVisible(clicks, clicks1)
    };
    function countDown1() {
        clicks1 += 1;
        document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML = clicks1;
        hiddenOrVisible(clicks, clicks1)

    };

    function hiddenOrVisible(clicks, clicks1){
      if (clicks === 12 && clicks1 === 13){
            document.getElementById("step1").style.display = 'block';
       }else{
            document.getElementById("step1").style.display = 'none';
        }
     }
```

Comment: Oh, that's awesome! I don't know why I didn't think about doing another function for that! Thank you for that! :D

Answer (score 0):

You can move the part where you hide the button to the click handling function.

```js
//var clickNeeded = 12;
let clicksOne = 0;
let clicksTwo = 0;


function countDown(id) {
    const buttonClicks = id === 'test1' ? ++clicksOne : ++clicksTwo;
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = buttonClicks;
    if (clicksOne == 12 && clicksTwo == 13){
        document.getElementById("step1").style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      document.getElementById("step1").style.display = 'none';
    }
};

function messageAfficher() {
    document.getElementById("enigme").style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
body{
    background-color: black; 
    
}

@font-face{
    font-family: 'hacked';
    src: url(font/Hacked-KerX.ttf);
    font-style: normal;
}

.header{
    text-align: center;
    margin: 50px 100px;
    font-family: hacked;
}

.header h1{
    color: purple;
    font-size: 80px;
    margin: 50px    
}

.header p{
    color: purple;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: justify;
    padding-right: 100px;
    padding-left: 100px; 
}

.enigme {
    color: aliceblue;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: hacked;
}

.step {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="fonction.js"></script> 
        <title>Escape Game</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
<!--===========================================================================================================================-->
    <body>
        
        <div class="header">
            <h1>Bienvenue dans cette aventure!</h1>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<br>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="step">
            <button id="test1" onclick="countDown(this.id)">0</button>
        </div>
        <div class="step">
            <button id="test2" onclick="countDown(this.id)">0</button>
        </div>
        <div class="step">
            <button id="step1" onclick="messageAfficher()" style="display:none">Où suis-je?</button>
        </div>
        <div class="enigme">
            <p id="enigme" style="display:none">Coordonne</p>
        </div>
        
    </body>
<!--===========================================================================================================================--> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you are missing:

1. You should check count condition every time when you are clicking on any button.
2. `hidden` is not a valid value for `display` property, replace `none` with `hidden`.

I will suggest you to avoid writing duplicate code on many places. Now these are the changes that you need to do,

```js
//var clickNeeded = 12;
var clicks = 0;
var clicks1 = 0;

function checkCondition(){
   if (clicks != 12 && clicks1 != 13){
     document.getElementById("step1").style.display = 'none';
   }
   else if (clicks == 12 && clicks1 == 13){
     document.getElementById("step1").style.display = 'block';
   }
}

function countDown() {
    clicks += 1;
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = clicks;
    checkCondition();
}

function countDown1() {
    clicks1 += 1;
    document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML = clicks1;
    checkCondition();
};

function messageAfficher() {
    document.getElementById("enigme").style.display = 'block';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I reduced your snippet to the bare minumum and also changed the number of clicks to 5. But otherwise I hope it does more or less, what you want: You can click up to the specified times on both buttons and then click once more to reveal the initially hidden button.

```js
const btns=[...document.querySelectorAll('[id^=test]')];
function makevisible(id){document.querySelector('#'+id).style.display='block'}
var maxClicks=5;
document.querySelector('.buttons').addEventListener('click',function(ev){
  var b=ev.target;
  if (b.id)
    if (b.id.substr(0,4)=='test') {
      if (b.textContent<maxClicks) b.textContent=+b.textContent+1
      else if(btns.reduce((s,v)=>+v.textContent+s,0)==2*maxClicks)
        makevisible('step1')
    } else if (b.id=="step1") makevisible('enigme')
})
```

```css
#step1, #enigme {display:none}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1>Bienvenue dans cette aventure!</h1>
  <p>Some irrelevant text (shortened).</p>
</div>
<div class="buttons">
<div class="step"><button id="test">0</button></div>
<div class="step"><button id="test1">0</button></div>
<div class="step"><button id="step1">Où suis-je?</button></div>
<div class="enigme">
  <p id="enigme">Coordonne</p>
</div>
</div>
```